# Boundary orientation of a cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Given a cylinder $M=S^1\times [0,1]$ with the counterclockwise orientation viewed from exterior as shown below:
[image]

I want to find orientation at $C_0$ and at $C_1$.

Note that at any $p=(x,y,0)\in C_0$, orientation in $T_p M$ is given by the ordered basis $B=\{(-y,x,0), e_3, (x,y,0)\}$. An outward pointing vector at $p$ is given by $-e_3=(0,0,-1)$.
Let $\omega$ be a non vanishing form on $M$ that represents the basis $B$, i.e., $\omega (B)>0$.

Now, the boundary orientation is given by contraction of $\omega$ with outward pointing vector $-e_3$, i.e., $i_X\omega$:

$(i_X\omega)_p ((-y,x,0),(x,y,0))=\omega_p(-e_3, (-y,x,0),(x,y,0))=\omega_p(B)>0$

So the basis $(-y,x,0),(x,y,0)$ is positively oriented. But this means that $C_0$ is clockwise oriented when viewed from the top.

But an answer key shows that $C_0$ is anticlockwise oriented when viewed from the top. Please explain what went wrong in the above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little comfused with your notation 'orientation in $T_pM$ is given by the ordered basis $B=\{(-y,x,0),e_3,(x,y,0)\}$'. The tangent space $T_pM$ is of dimension 2 and with orientation $\{(-y,x,0),e_3=(0,0,1)\}$.

Comment: My bad! Thanks a lot for pointing that out.

Comment: So at a point (x,y,z) on the cylinder, the positively oriented basis is $\{(-y,x,0), e_3\}$. This is because the question says counterclockwise orientation. Now, let w be a non vanishing form on the cylinder M representing the basis. It exists because M is orientable. Now, I find its contraction with the outward pointing vector -$e_3$ as follows: $i_{-e_3}w((-y,x,0))= w(-e_3, (-y,x,0))=- w(e_3,(-y,x,0))= w((-y,x,0), e_3)>0$
So the orientation on the circle is anticlockwise as viewed from the top.

Comment: You’re welcome! I think your comment is right.